# How to debug a .desktop file?

Tags: linux, .desktop, flatpak

I've installed Gnome Boxes, Gnome Builder and Peek through flatpak, and when I click the app in the aplication menu, they don't start.
And I don't know why, so I just looked at the .desktop in `/var/lib/flatpak/exports/share/applications` file and change `Terminal=true` but it does not show any terminal.
Then I tried to run the `Exec` parameter in terminal, and it works fine, no errors.
And finally I remove all flags in `Exec` but still does nothing
Anyone that has this same issue? Any solution?
Or at least someone knows how to debug a .desktop file?

Gnome Boxes

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Boxes
GenericName=Virtual machine viewer/manager
Comment=View and use virtual machines
Keywords=virtual machine;vm;
Exec=/usr/bin/flatpak run org.gnome.Boxes @@u %U @@
Icon=org.gnome.Boxes
Terminal=true
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Categories=GNOME;GTK;System;Development;Emulator;
MimeType=application/x-cd-image;
DBusActivatable=true
X-Flatpak=org.gnome.Boxes
```

Gnome Builder

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Builder
Comment=Build software for GNOME
Exec=/usr/bin/flatpak run --branch=stable --arch=x86_64 --command=gnome-builder --file-forwarding org.gnome.Builder @@u %U @@
Icon=org.gnome.Builder
DBusActivatable=true
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Development;IDE;
Keywords=Build;Develop;
MimeType=text/x-c;text/x-csrc;text/x-changelog;text/x-chdr;text/x-c++hdr;text/x-python;application/x-python;application/javascript;application/x-javascript;text/x-javascript;text/javascript;text/x-js;text/x-shellscript;application/x-shellscript;text/x-sh;text/x-vala;text/x-makefile;text/x-c++;text/x-cpp;text/x-c++src;text/css;application/x-gnome-app-info;application/x-desktop;text/x-go;text/html;text/x-markdown;application/json;application/x-m4;application/xml;text/xml;application/x-yaml;text/x-sql;application/x-ruby;text/x-ruby;text/x-pkg-config;text/x-lua;text/x-php;application/x-php;text/x-php-source;application/x-php-source;text/x-perl;application/x-perl;
X-Flatpak-RenamedFrom=gnome-builder;
Actions=new-window;create-project;clone-repo;new-editor;dspy;
X-Flatpak=org.gnome.Builder

[Desktop Action new-window]
Name=Open a Project
Exec=/usr/bin/flatpak run --branch=stable --arch=x86_64 --command=gnome-builder org.gnome.Builder --greeter

[Desktop Action create-project]
Name=Start New Project
Exec=/usr/bin/flatpak run --branch=stable --arch=x86_64 --command=gnome-builder org.gnome.Builder --create-project

[Desktop Action clone-repo]
Name=Clone Repository
Exec=/usr/bin/flatpak run --branch=stable --arch=x86_64 --command=gnome-builder org.gnome.Builder --clone

[Desktop Action new-editor]
Name=New Editor Workspace
Exec=/usr/bin/flatpak run --branch=stable --arch=x86_64 --command=gnome-builder org.gnome.Builder --editor

[Desktop Action dspy]
Name=D-Bus Inspector
Exec=/usr/bin/flatpak run --branch=stable --arch=x86_64 --command=gnome-builder org.gnome.Builder --dspy
```

Peek

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Peek
Exec=/usr/bin/flatpak run com.uploadedlobster.peek @@u %U @@
GenericName=Animated GIF recorder
Comment=Record short animated GIF images from your screen
Keywords=screencast;screen recorder;screen capture;GIF;WebM;APNG;
Icon=com.uploadedlobster.peek
Type=Application
Categories=GTK;GNOME;Graphics;2DGraphics;AudioVideo;Video;Recorder;
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=true
DBusActivatable=true
X-Flatpak=com.uploadedlobster.peek
```

### Basic OS info

```
Distro: Void Linux (musl)
Architecture: x64
DE: Gnome 40 (with Wayland)
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was simple, delete the symlink to the .desktop file and manually create another one.

New Gnome Boxes .desktop file

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Boxes
Icon=org.gnome.Boxes
Exec=/usr/bin/flatpak run org.gnome.Boxes
Comment=Gnome boxes
Type=Application
```